# assignment operator on objects

Tags: c++, object, pointers, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I'm new to programming, based on google search, first hit was always 'stackoverflow',
it has been very helpful. I didn't get an answer for this part. Its a simple code, I've
been trying to learn how assignment operator works on objects. I've looked  into some
books, there are no examples.

```
// wood.h
using namespace std;

///#include <cstdio>
//#include <cstdlib>
//#include <iostream>
//#include <string>

class wood {
public :
 wood (void);
  wood (string type, string color) ;
  void display(void);`
  wood  & operator=(const wood &copy         );
  wood  & operator=(const wood * const &copy );
  private :
  string     m_color;
  string     m_name;
  };
 // wood.cc
 wood::  wood (string name, string color) {
    m_name = name;
   m_color = color;
}
 wood & wood::operator=(const wood &from) {`
  cout << "calling assignment construction of" << from.m_name  << endl;
   m_name   = from.m_name;
   m_color   = from.m_color;
  return *this;
}
void wood::display (void) {`
  cout << "name: " << m_name << " color: " << m_color << endl;
} 
// test_wood.cc
int main () 
{
   wood *p_x, *p_y;`
   wood    a("abc", "blue");
   wood    b("def", "red" );
   a.display();
   b.display();
   b = a;          // calls assignment operator, as I expected`
   a.display();`
   b.display();`
   p_x = new wood ("xyz", "white");
   p_y = new wood ("pqr", "black");
   p_x->display();`
   p_y->display();`

   p_y = p_x;   // Here it doesn't call assignment operator, Why?
               // It does only pointer assignement, p_y original pointer goes into ether.
   p_x->display();`
   p_y->display();`
   printf("p_x:%p, p_y:%p \n", p_x, p_y); 

 return 0;
}
 //output:
name: abc color: blue
name: def color: red
calling assignment construction abc
name: abc color: blue
name: abc color: blue
name: xyz color: white
name: pqr color: black
name: xyz color: white
name: xyz color: white
p_x:0x9be4068, p_y:0x9be4068
```

Comment: If you are new to programming, the code you are looking at is bit too much for you, IMO. What they are doing is operator overloading for assignment operator. What it does is override the way '=' works by assigning the name and color of the wood.. but by default it will only assign the address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is 'operator overloading'. In this technique, you define a new behavior for an existing operator, in this case it is '='. Basically when this operator is called in main(), it takes it's right hand side operand and assigns it's member values to the members of the left hand side operand.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, `p_y = p_x;` is just a simple pointer assignment.
This is because you overloaded the assignment operator for `wood`, not for `wood*`.

Change `p_y = p_x;` to `*p_y = *p_x;`.

You could implement a free function to overload `operator=` for `wood*`, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks to **Henrik and Rakesh**. I'm bit puzzled at this '=' assignment operator overload, how come it works in the former case i.e  b = a; where 'a' and 'b' are created in stack, whereas p_y = p_x; where p_y & p_x are created in heap.  How to create assignment operator overload for 'wood*'?. I appreciate 'stackoverflow' group, people are really smart, my fundamentals are getting clear by reading our Q&A/FAQs. _italic_ doing this, i.e >>Change `p_y = p_x; to *p_y = *p_x;` works, Thanks.